# how to categorize dynamic inputs in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have two types of input fields generated dynamically by add more buttons one for adding categories and the other for sub categories. I have to group different sub categories to a single main category. how can insert them in to mysql database, someone please help me, thanks in advance.

```
<html>
<body>
<button type="button" value="add more" 
onClick="addInput_a('dynamicInput_a');"></button>
<div id="dynamicInput_a">
<label>Category</label>
<input name="a_meaning[]">                        
</div>
<button type="button" value="add more"  onClick="addInput_b('dynamicInput_b');"></button>
<div id="dynamicInput_b">
<label>Sub Category</label>
<input name="b_meaning[]">                        
</div>

<script>
var counter = 1;
var limit = 25;
function addInput_a(divName){
 if (counter == limit)  {
      alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
 }
 else {
      var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
      newdiv.innerHTML = " <br> <label>Category</label><input 
name='a_meaning[]'>";
      document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
      counter++;
 }
}
</script>
       <script>
var counter = 1;
var limit = 25;
function addInput_b(divName){
 if (counter == limit)  {
      alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
 }
 else {
      var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
      newdiv.innerHTML = " <br> <label>Sub Category</label><input 
name='b_meaning[]'>";
      document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
      counter++;
 }
}
</script>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Where is your php code?

Comment: i have no idea how to write php code to categorize them

Comment: i have to insert them as category1-subcategory1,subcategry2, etc and category2-sub cat1,sub cat2,etc..

Comment: Firstly! You should learn basics of php+mysqli from [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp). No one would like to write code for you until you tried something.

Comment: another thing is that, you have 2 variables counter & limit 2 times. rename them as counter1, limit1 &counter2, limit2.

Comment: i can insert them separately as categories and sub categories by using php and mysql.but i cant combine.. anyway let me try and thanks